# Ruby gem for extracting IPTC data from JPEG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, metadata, iptc

I'm looking for a gem to use with Rails 3 to extract some basic IPTC metadata from jpeg files (title, caption, ...). I have found  [ruby-iptc](https://github.com/jkraemer/ruby-iptc) but I have no clue of how to use it having found no documentation or examples. Help anybody?

Answer (score 2):

I use the gem [mini_exiftool](https://github.com/janfri/mini_exiftool) as a binding for the seperate commandline tool [exiftool.exe](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)
It can read and change title and IPTC metadata.

```
require 'mini_exiftool'

# Reading meta data
photo = MiniExiftool.new 'heroes.jpg'
puts photo.title

# Writing meta data
photo = MiniExiftool.new 'heroes.jpg'
photo.title = 'This is the new title'
photo.rating = 20
photo.save
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, pretty well documented, not that active but it should suit your needs [Exif reader](https://github.com/remvee/exifr).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It partly works - I can retrieve all EXIF and some additional meta-data e.g. caption (using the image_description method on the EXIF object you create), but not title. The EXIF object defines  an 'iptc' method but this returns nil! Anyway, this will fit my purpose - I will add some internal structure to the caption part and parse it as I read it.